# The geometric meaning of spectrum

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$R$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$. From commutative algebra, we know that $R$ is isomorphic to $k[x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}]/J$ where $J$ is a proper ideal of $k[x_{1},x_{2},\dots, x_{n}]$. Now we want to prove that spectrum of $R$ is equal to $V(J)$ which is corresponding algebraic variety of $J$.

If $J=I(V)$, I know the fact that we have a one-one correspondence between algebraic set $V$ and spectrum of $R$. By Hilbert nullstellensatz, we know that $I(V(J))=\sqrt{J}$ (I'm sorry about abuse of notation). If $J=\sqrt{J}$, we are done. But if $J\in \sqrt{J}$, one way I wanna try is to prove that $k[x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}]/J\cong  k[x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}]/\sqrt{J}$. I'm stuck with this part. Is my direction right?

Answer (score 2):

The thing you're trying to prove is false! Consider

$$ R = k[x] / (x^2) $$

The underlying topological space of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is just a single point: the origin $O$ of the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1_k$.

The relevant commutative algebra fact is that if $P$ is prime, then $P \mid J$ if and only if $P \mid \sqrt{J}$. In fact,

$$ \sqrt{J} = \bigcap_{P \mid J} P $$

Every counterexample, however, is a ring with nontrivial nilpotents. If $R$ is a *reduced* ring, then you're guaranteed $J = \sqrt{J}$.

---

Note, however, that $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ has a different ring of functions than $O$ does, so $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is not *actually* isomorphic to $O$ — they are only isomorphic if you forget the functions and consider just the topological space.

If you remember the ring of functions, then $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ acts like $O$ together with its tangent space; $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ acts like an infinitesimal line element centered on $O$.